# Limit in excel data validation source code

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, dropdownlist

I have an excel file with two sheets. The second sheet (**Report**) contains data validation cells based on the first sheet (**Data**). From the second sheet, the drop-down list that displays in the **Select XXX** depends on the selection in the **Generate Report**. When the **Generate Report** is set to anything beyond the first five in its list, the **Select XXX** displays year as a default list (no problem with this) via the code `...INDIRECT("Year")...`. The problem is that excel does not allow for addition of more code (seems I hit the limit). The question is - how can I manipulate this code to accommodate every option in the **Generate Report**? or perhaps, is there another method to implement?

The data validation source code for the drop-down list is `=IF($B$4=Data!$Q$5,INDIRECT("Client"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$6,INDIRECT("Month"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$7,INDIRECT("Product_Service"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$8,INDIRECT("Sector"), IF($B$4=Data!$Q$9,INDIRECT("Trans_Type"),INDIRECT("Year"))))))`

Please, see the sample file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKkGHjlJzLQqx4J9kyd_bCKG4r0Q7HkG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Basis table, add a column with the table name matching the basis , and then use VLOOKUP function in the data validation.
This will shorten your formula .

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is gonna be the best way to go about it as demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987867/limit-with-creating-a-drop-down-list-dependent-on-a-selection-in-excel/62989597#62989597